# having trouble with a admin login form

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I am currently working on making a admin login form for a website I am making the problem is that whenever I try and submit the form it automatically accepts it and doesn't not display the error message for invalid credentials if I enter the wrong value or nothing at all

```
<?php require_once('dbadmin.php');?>
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
if(isset($_POST['adminlogin'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['user']);
    $password = md5(trim($_POST['password'])); // wrap the trim() function with md5() function
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Invalid query: ".mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        $confim = '<h2 style="color:red;">Invalid Credentials!</h2>';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        $confirm = '<h2> Login Successful</h2>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <header><img src="images/eastersealsclevelogo.png" alt="Easter Seals Logo" width="445" height="300"/> </header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="signup.php" class="current">Run Sign-Up</a></li>
           <li><a href="refer.php" class="current">Refer-a-Friend</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    <h1>Enter Your Login Information</h1>
    <?php if(isset($confirm)) echo $confirm; ?> 
       <form method="post" name="adminlogin" id="adminlogin" title="adminlogin" action="admin_login.php">
    <p>User: <br> <input type="text" name="user"></p>
    <p>Password: <br><input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="adminlogin" id="adminlogin" value="Login"></p>
</form>
    </p>
    <footer></footer>
   </body>

</html>
```

error i keep getting now
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in filepath/admin_login.php on line 10
Invalid query:

Comment: Check your connection script if there are still mysql extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is hard-coded, so if you have a username of 'username' with a password of 'password', the SELECT will always find it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'username' AND password = 'password'";
```

replace it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

Don't use the **mysql** functions because they have been deprecated, use **mysqli** or **PDO**.

Comment: Okay i changed the mysql function to a mysqli one and now it keeps showing a error when i click submit 

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in filepath/admin_login.php on line 10
Invalid query: